# Saving images from scrapy integrated with django

Tags: django, scrapy

I’ve got a Scrapy project hooked up to a Django project and everything is working fine (i.e. when I run my scraper, I’m able to save items to the DB).

I’m trying to add an image scraper to my project and I can’t get it to work. I can get Scrapy’s image scraper to work on its own but not when hooked up to the Django project

The error I’m getting is the following:

```
  File "/Users/junaid/Desktop/clscraper2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/junaid/Desktop/clscraper2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/media.py", line 79, in process_item
    requests = arg_to_iter(self.get_media_requests(item, info))
  File "/Users/junaid/Desktop/clscraper2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 155, in get_media_requests
    return [Request(x) for x in item.get(self.images_urls_field, [])]
  File "/Users/junaid/Desktop/clscraper2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 155, in <listcomp>
    return [Request(x) for x in item.get(self.images_urls_field, [])]
  File "/Users/junaid/Desktop/clscraper2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "/Users/junaid/Desktop/clscraper2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 62, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h
```

Here’s my project:

Models.py

```
class atl_sale_listing(models.Model):
    metro_area = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=False)
    listing_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)  #must be unique
    url = models.CharField(max_length=450, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    tax = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Items.py --
Note - I'm adding the image_urls and images field to the django item  object

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_djangoitem import DjangoItem
from realestate_app.models import atl_sale_listing

class AtlSaleListingItem(DjangoItem):
    django_model = atl_sale_listing

    image_urls = scrapy.Field() #added
    images =  scrapy.Field() #added
```

spider.py

```
import scrapy
from re_scraper.items import AtlSaleListingItem

from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class AtlListings2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "atl_buy_testing"
    allowed_domains = ["www.something.com"]
    start_urls = ['www.something.com/something2',
                  ] #specify the filter in the url

    def parse(self, response):
        listings = response.xpath('//div[@class="cardone "]')
        order = 1

        for listing in listings:
            url = listing.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()
            yield scrapy.Request(url,
                            callback=self.parse_listing)


    def parse_listing(self, response):

        status = response.xpath('//*[@class="text-orange"]/text()').extract_first()
        price = response.xpath('//*[@class="price"]/text()').extract_first()

        image_urls = response.xpath('//img/@data-img')[0].extract() #added image field  here

        yield AtlSaleListingItem(
            status = status,
            price = price,

            image_urls = image_urls,
            )
```

settings.py

```
from random import random
import os
import sys


DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'realestate.settings'

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('.')))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'realestate.settings'

import django
django.setup()

BOT_NAME = 're_scraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['re_scraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 're_scraper.spiders'


# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   're_scraper.pipelines.AtlListingPipeline': 5,
   'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1,
}

IMAGES_STORE = '/Users/user1/desktop/movoto_images'
```

Any help here would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're having `ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h`, comes from a request you are making in the media pipeline. You are requesting an url without a scheme, such as `http(s)`, `ftp`, `file`, `data`, `irc`, and others... Exhaustiv list [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml).

Check the urls you are getting from `image_urls = response.xpath('//img/@data-img')[0].extract()`. It needs to be a list of urls *(don't forget the scheme !)*

Comment: Thanks. the xpath code for my 'image_urls' variable was extracting a string, changing it to a list solved my problem